# How to diagnose poor Flask performance?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

I have a Flask app and PostgreSQL database. From some point in time the app started behaving erratically: response times are very high, and for some reason the Flask app process takes 60% of available memory. Eventually (ater several days of uptime, roughly from 3 to 5) application becomes unusable, due to every interaction with it taking more then minute to complete or timing out outright.

How can I diagnose this behavior?  Is there a proper way to determine where the delays come from and why so much memory is used?

Answer (score 3):

You can profile the Flask app using werkzeug's builtin profiler by adding the following code:

```
from werkzeug.contrib.profiler import ProfilerMiddleware
from app import app

app.config['PROFILE'] = True
app.wsgi_app = ProfilerMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, restrictions = [30])
app.run(debug = True)
```

Or you could run it from the commandline with [Flask-runner](https://flask-runner.readthedocs.org/):

```
$ python hello.py --profile --profile-count 30
```

And regarding Postgres, take a look at the [logging documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-logging.html).